# is it possible to test web app using Xcui?

Tags: xcode, macos, automation

I am looking into Xcode and Xcui for web app and cannot get it work. to start up recording, build or whatsoever it needs a valid executable which I don't have since i am not building an app. is there any way to launch Safari as the app and then record it and run tests?
i know there's Appium and other tools but wondering if it's possible and if so I would be keen to implement some in swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: This is a super hacky way to get it done:

I think you would have to create a quick application that holds a web view in the app, that launches to your respective web page.

- You can write automated tests for this app which will simply land you on your web page
- You will not have access to elements, like table views, cells, or anything in the XCUIelement tree
- You will have to do everything based on frames and coordinates

You can determine where all your elements are and set them up as variables and call them like this:

```
`let myButton = XCUIApplication().windows.element(boundBy: 0).coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.30))`
```

`myButton.tap()`

Not ideal but if you want to use swift to learn and move things around its possible

Answer (score 0):

As far as XCUI testing is concerned, it was basically made to test the integration flow of an iOS app. As a result it can ONLY test native view controllers. As far as the web view is concerned, it should be tested at the web level and not at the application level.